# AWS AppSync Android NullPointerException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, nullpointerexception, aws-appsync

```
public void queryData(){
    if(mAWSAppSyncClient == null){
        mAWSAppSyncClient = ClientFactory.getInstance(this);
    }

    mAWSAppSyncClient.query(GetCounterDataQuery.builder().build())
            .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK)
            .enqueue(postsCallback);
}

public GraphQLCall.Callback<GetCounterDataQuery.Data> postsCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<GetCounterDataQuery.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull final Response<GetCounterDataQuery.Data> response) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(response.data()!=null) {
                    TextView value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterValue);
                    value.setText(response.data().getCounterData().counterData);
                    TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterName);
                    Name.setText(response.data().getCounterData().counterName);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

In the GraphQL Callback method, response.data() I am getting NullPointerException.(Even though I am using if condition to check null ) How to resolve?

Thanks for the replies,

Now its working fine with this solution, In response callback I have added some value if the response is NULL, it wouldn't be null in my case.

```
  public void queryData(String id){
    if(mAWSAppSyncClient == null){
        mAWSAppSyncClient = ClientFactory.getInstance(this);
    }

    mAWSAppSyncClient.query(GetCounterQuery.builder().id(id).build())
            .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK)
            .enqueue(postsCallback);
}

public GraphQLCall.Callback<GetCounterQuery.Data> postsCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<GetCounterQuery.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull final Response<GetCounterQuery.Data> response) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(response != null) {
                    String valuestr = (response.data().getCounter().counterNumber != NULL ) ? (response.data().getCounter().counterNumber).toString() : "66";
                    TextView value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterValue);
                    value.setText(valuestr);

                    String nameStr= (response.data().getCounter().counterName).isEmpty() ? "HAHAHA" : response.data().getCounter().counterName;
                    TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterName);
                    Name.setText(nameStr);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {


    }
};
```

Comment: maybe the `response` variable is `null`?

Comment: Can you share your graphql schema? Does it have GetCounterDataQuery?